# Android app not running on new phone

Tags: android

My app ran on my old phone but even though I've made no changes, it won't run on my new phone on a later version of Android. The mininum SDK setting for the project is Android 4.4. In the Run box it just says Waiting for process to come online and on my phone the app doesn't run, and it doesn't display any message. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043149/android-studio-cant-run-application-on-device-stuck-on-waiting-for-process

Comment: I looked at this page, There is no android:launchMode="standard" in my manifest so it's not that. I also tried File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and Launch - Default Activity is already set. I'm not sure if com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 in build.gradle should be changed to something else.

Comment: which phone you are using? Check if its getting detected by following adb command: $adb devices

Comment: it's a Huawei P9 Lite and it is there when I type the adb devices command

Answer (score 0):

check your  **targetSdkVersion** if your android phone version 6.0 then set 23 else if 7.0 then set 24-25

Comment: It's already set to 23 and the version of Android on the new phone is 6.0