# No emulators will run in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I have `Android Studio 2.3.3` and I can run code on my device no problem.  But, in this version, none of the Emulators work.  I had a previous version at the end of 2016 and everything worked fine.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFm44FUDw9A&feature=youtu.be) showing an attempt to run a Nexus 6P emulator from AVD Manager.  It seems to open then immediately closes.  The same happens when trying to run any app, regardless of the SDK used or device emulated.

As I read somewhere here in SO, I quit Docker too but still the same problem.  I also tried changing the `Graphics` setting from `Automatic` to `Software` but that didn't help.

Any help would be great.

Comment: have you tried installing a new emulator?

Comment: @wvdz Thanks.  Yeah, I have.  I'm just trying "File" --> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" as suggested by somebody here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043149/android-studio-cant-run-application-on-device-stuck-on-waiting-for-process  - Tried it but it didn't help

Comment: I had this same problem some months ago, cannot quite remember what I did to fix, but I think that just deleting and creating emulators or reinstalling  everything did the trick.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Thanks.  Yeah, I'm sure a solution will be found and when it is, I'll post the answer here.  Cheers

Comment: If you are on a Mac and running Docker, quit Docker and try again. That worked for me. If that works, I give credit to the person who answered a similar question on a different post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43515962/1532488

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to elaborate on my previous comment to the OP.

If you are on a Mac and running Docker, you may have a conflict that prevents the Android emulator from running. It appears that there was a conflict in Intel's Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) prior to 6.1.1 that caused the emulator not to load if Docker was running.

I have upgraded to 6.1.2 and I am now able to run Docker and my emulator.

Reference links:

[Description of conflict](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24530)

[Download for HAXM 6.1.2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

[Instructions to remove previous HAXM install and replace it with the 6.1.2 download](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks but as I said in the question, I'd already tried quitting Docker and it didn't help.